# Why does string to int conversion not print the number 0 if its at first index

Tags: c, atoi, strtol

I am wondering as to why when converting strings to int with either atoi or strtol it does not print the number 0 if its the first index, take this code for example

```
char s[] = "0929784";
long temp = strtol(s, NULL, 10);
printf("%li", temp);

OUTPUT: 929784
```

is there a way to have the 0 print?

Comment: uh, no ? Because 0929784 is not a number. Worst, in C, number beginning by 0 are octal base, so 0929784 is false.

Comment: yes, printf("%s\n", s); muhaha

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with strtol/atoi but everything to do with how you print the number.

Comment: There definitely are dupes to this, but closing a C question as being a dupe to a C++question is a bad choice.

Comment: I re-opened. Please don't use C++ posts for duplicates to C questions. String handling in particular is very different in the two languages.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
char s[] = "0929784";
size_t len = strlen(s);
long temp = strtol(s, NULL, 10);
printf("%0*li", (int) len, temp);
```

Details are [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html).

A more subtle and even safer approach would be:

```
char s[] = "0929784FooBarBlaBla"; 
char * endptr; 
long temp = strtol(s, &endptr, 10);
printf("%0*li", (int) (endptr - s), temp);
```

More details are [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html).

Comment: this is the most pedantic answer indeed

Comment: Good answer but could be improved further with `char* endptr; long temp = strtol(s, &endptr, 10); ptrdiff_t len = endptr - s;`, in case the input string contains invalid characters.

Comment: @Lundin: Okok, you are right. :}

Comment: @alk Feel free to grab that code and improve the answer further.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` will print the `long` in the best way possible, and that includes dropping any leading zeros.

For example, if someone asks you to write your age, you wouldn't write `028` if you were `28` would you? Even more sinister in C, a leading 0 denotes an *octal* constant, so actually `028` makes no sense as a number in C. Formally `0` is an octal constant although that, of course, doesn't matter.

Comment: It makes sense, thank you for your help, I guess its just something I have to delve deeper into understanding.

Answer (score 1):

An int basically stores leading zeros. The problem that you are running into is that you are not printing the leading zeros that are there. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942348/is-it-possible-to-store-a-leading-zero-in-an-int?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa))

`printf` manual:

> 0 A zero '0' character indicating that zero-padding should be used
>   rather than blank-padding. A '-' overrides a '0' if both are used;

So use:

```
printf("%0*li", (int) strlen(s), temp);
```

Comment: As I pointed already in a comment to other answer it is a wrong approach because if the string does not contain a leading zero nevertheless zeroes will be outputted due to formatting.

Comment: see my edited post, it is the fault of printf to not print leading zero, an int stores them

Comment: Oops sorry, made mistake in edit. Thanks for Pointing this out will correct it.

Comment: Corrected it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Try

```
printf("%07li", temp);
```

Comment: It is a wrong approach because if the string does not contain a leading zero nevertheless it will be outputted due to formating.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Then don't convert it to an integer. It sounds as if you don't want a number. You want a string apparently.